# How to put an Image in image with Android?

Tags: android

I need some help, because I am developing an application which I need to do that an **image(2)** is in other **image(1)**, and when I move the **image(1)**, the **image(2)** move to the same place.

Please, give me some information or anything to search. Thanks

Comment: May be [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) will help you

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a regular ImageView. An ImageView has both a Background and Image, both of which can be drawables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a class which extends View.  You'll then need to overrode the `onDraw` method and the `onTouchEvent` to make it respond to user input.  This way you can do anything you like in the `onDraw` as you have access to the canvas directly.